# Select all text from targeted string excluding whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which looks something like the following

```
&pound;&nbsp;                               0.00<br>
```

I am only interested in extracting the decimal value found in the string between the `£` and `<br>` tag.
I currently have a regular expression which is:

```
(?<=&pound;&nbsp;)(.*?)(?=\<br>)
```

which gives the following result

```
                       0.00
```

I need to make sure that no white-spaces are included in the final result, I tried something like the following...

```
(?<=&pound;&nbsp;\s*)(.*?)(?=\<br>)
```

which is obviously wrong and means I have no idea what I am doing.

How do I make sure I extract the correct decimal value minus any whitespaces?

```
e.g. 
0.00
instead of 
           0.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your resulting string?

```
$result = trim($result);
```

Comment: +1 Sometimes the simplest answers are the best. Why write a complicated regex? `trim()` is so much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Why first using a too complex regex that does just the half of the work? A working regex pattern is simpler that the one from the question. And will not need `trim()`. Check my answer

Comment: @hek2mgl - Because the OP's regex does what s/he wants it to do (find a number preceded by a particular sequence of characters). Yours does not do that.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 no it doesn't. It returns the decimal with whitespaces. Requested is a regex pattern that matches only the decimal without whitespaces. Therefore the question on stackoverflow

Comment: @hek2mgl - your forgot the second part: "found in the string between the £ and <br> tag". Your answer does not do that. This is still the simplest answer that works.

Comment: I already considered using trim() but I was hoping for something more clean cut.

Comment: Complicating a regex only to remove terminal whitespace is markedly less clean cut, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the decimal value the regex pattern should look like in the following example. The example prints all decimals that where found in your search string.

```
<?php

$string = '&pound;&nbsp;

                          5.00<br><br><br>

                          Shipping&nbsp;&pound;&nbsp;3.35<br><br><b>Total&nbsp;&pound;&nbsp;

                             8.35<br></b>';

$pattern = '/&pound;&nbsp;\s*(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)<br>/u';

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die('error in regex');
}

// output the decimals
if($result > 0) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $decimal) {
        echo $decimal, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Output:
//
// 5.00
// 3.35
// 8.35
```

Note that the pattern will match positive and negative decimals

Comment: Clean, simple, and all without needing additional lookaheads or lookbehinds. It's the way I would do it.

Comment: I think you've failed to realize that the OP is matching text within a larger document. I don't think s/he wants to match just any number, but a number preceded by `&pound;&nbsp;`. Your regex does not do that.

Comment: The OP tells 'I have a string which looks something like the following :' There is nothing said about larger document. Do not assume too much

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I just kept the pattern as simple as possible to point the questioner on how to select only the decimal. I've updated the pattern to a more complex one. I hope you are happy now. ;)

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, I wanted to just extract the decimal number between the £ and <br> tag excluding anything else such as whites-space, this does not solve my problem http://regexr.com?33iq2

Comment: @mk_89 You can also test using this site http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php . Note that you'll have to make sure that the regex test site is for **PHP** regular expressiones. There are differences between different implementations. Also note, that the decimals are stored in $matches[1] and not in $matches[0]

Comment: @mk_89 I slightly enhanced my example. I had a look at regexr.com You'll have to enable 'global' and move the mouse over the blue matches. A yellow popup shows up and there you can see the decimal as submatch. However, I think there are better sites to test regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify regexp?

```
/&pound;&nbsp;\s*([0-9\.]+)<br>/u
```

**Update:** More general case:

```
/&pound;.*([0-9\.]+)<br>/u
```

Comment: If you look at my original post you will see that I am trying to get the value after the £ pound sign and before the <br> tag, I am only trying to extract the decimal number from the string and nothing more.

Comment: You'll match decimal number using this regexp. You need something else?

Answer (score 0):

This works;

```
$s = '&pound;&nbsp;                               0.00<br>';
preg_match('~&(.*?);\s+([\d\.]+)~i', $s, $m);
// or
// preg_match('~&(\w+);\s+([\d\.]+)~i', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Out;

```
Array
(
    [0] => &pound;&nbsp;                               0.00
    [1] => pound;&nbsp
    [2] => 0.00
)
```